# Deleting a binary data image by a instance

Tags: swift, core-data

In my Swift code below the goal is to delete a binary data by the corresponding `var Int`. The `var Int` is called `counterImage`. My code right now is causing a runtime error of counterImage

> 'Cannot convert value of type 'Int' to expected argument type 'TheBook''

What can I do to fix this? All the code is right here. You would have to add the images but after that you can just copy and paste the code.

[image: pic]

```
import UIKit;import CoreData

class ViewController: UIViewController {   
    var counterImage = 1    

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let gwen = UIImage(named: "h")
        if let imageData = gwen.self?.pngData() {
            helpImage.shareInstance.saveImage(data: imageData)
        }
        let gwen2 = UIImage(named: "hh")
        if let imageData = gwen2.self?.pngData() {
            helpImage.shareInstance.saveImage(data: imageData)
        }
        helpImage.shareInstance.deleteObject(user: counterImage)  
    }
}

class helpImage: UIViewController{
    private class func getContext() -> NSManagedObjectContext {
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        return appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    }

    static let shareInstance = helpImage()
    let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

    func saveImage(data: Data) {
        let imageInstance = TheBook(context: context)
        imageInstance.pic = data  
        do {
            try context.save()
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }

    func deleteObject(user: TheBook) {
        let context = helpImage.getContext()
        let delete = NSBatchDeleteRequest(fetchRequest: TheBook.fetchRequest())
        do {
            try context.execute(delete)
        } catch {
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: What does *corresponding* mean? And what does `.self?` mean? By the way it’s not a good practice to save images as raw Data in CoreData. Save the image on disk and only the URL in CoreData. Maybe this solves even your issue.

Comment: The error is pretty obvious. Your `deleteObject` function has a `user` parameter of type `TheBook` but you attempt to call it passing in the `Int` property `counterImage`.

Comment: @HangarRash what would I put to delete the 2nd object

Comment: You need a better "TheBook" entity with more attributes than just the image data.